# Terminating decimal

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double a,b,res;

while(cin>>a>>b)
{
    res = a/b;

    if((res*b) == a)
        cout<<"Terminates"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Does not terminate"<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

So, here is my code to see if a/b results in terminating decimal or not. Some input is generating correct output, like:

> 1/3 : Does not terminates,
>
> 1/9 : Does not terminates,
>
> 1/7 : Does not terminates,
>
> 22/7 : Does not terminates,
>
> 1/2 : Terminates.

Except for 1/5 which should show: `1/5 : Terminates`, but the output is: `Does not terminates`.

I know there are many issues for C++ floating points,tried google but it's like a puzzle.

Comment: In binary arithmetic, 1/5 is a non-terminating fraction.

Comment: could you explain more please @PatriciaShanahan

Comment: ok,i kind of get it @PatriciaShanahan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an easy way to ask whether a ratio has an exact, terminating representation in a given radix, in your case 10.

Step 1 is to reduce it to its lowest terms. Divide top and bottom by their highest common factor.

Now only the denominator matters. If every one of its prime factors is also a prime factor of the radix, the fraction will terminate in that radix. 5 is a prime factor of 10, so 1/5 terminates in decimal. 5 is not a prime factor of 2, so 1/5 does not terminate in binary.

Answer (score 3):

Only fractions like 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 and so on (or sum of such) are represented precisely in `double`. All others are approximations. So as a results `1/5 * 5` could equal `0.9999999999`.

That's why one should never ever compare floating point numbers for equality (at least not without required precision, like `testedValue - num < precision`).

Comment: What can i do here then ? @Hcorg

Comment: either choose a precision for comparison or use some library for working on fractions. Fixed point arithmetic could help (for example Boost Multiprecission)

Comment: The problem i was solving says : take 2 integer a and b input & check a/b results in terminating decimal . I took input as double cause int/int division will result in integer  & upcasting will results the same @Hcorg

Comment: you can't do that using floating point arithmetic, but you do not need to use it - see other answers :)